# sql to query set

Tags: python, sql, django

I have 2 tables:

```
puzz_meeting_candidats :
   - id, canceled, candidat_id, meeting_id
puzz_meeting :
   - id, Client
```

I have a query follow:

```
SELECT U1.`candidat_id` AS Col1 FROM `puzz_meeting_candidats` U1 
INNER JOIN `puzz_meeting` U2 ON ( U1.`meeting_id` = U2.`id` ) 
WHERE U2.`Client` LIKE '%ipsos%' AND U1.`canceled` = False
```

How to convert query above to queryset

Comment: This is a very simple query. What did you try?

Comment: I'm newbie in django so could you please help me to convert it into query set in django !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-sql : sql to query set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196310/django-sql-sql-to-query-set)

Answer (score 1):

Puzz_Meeting_Candidats.objects.filter(canceled=False, meeting__Client__contains='ipsos')