# django-sql : sql to query set

Tags: python, sql, django

I have 2 table follow as:

```
puzz_meeting_candidats :
  - id, canceled, candidat_id, meeting_id
puzz_meeting :
  - id, Client
```

I have a query follow:

```
SELECT U1.`candidat_id` AS Col1 FROM `puzz_meeting_candidats` U1 
 INNER JOIN `puzz_meeting` U2 ON ( U1.`meeting_id` = U2.`id` ) 
 WHERE U2.`Client` LIKE '%ipsos%' AND U1.`canceled` = False
```

How to convert query above to queryset with condition using Q object in Django. I'm so thank for your helping!!! :D

Comment: Where is your question? please edit it ,your question is unclear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models look like something this:

```
class PuzzMeetingCandidats(models.Model):
    canceled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    candidat = models.ForeignKey('Candidat')
    meeting = models.ForeignKey('PuzzMeeting')

class PuzzMeeting(models.Model):
    Client = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
```

You can write a query like this without using `Q`:

```
qs = PuzzMeetingCandidats.objects.filter(
    canceled=False, 
    meeting__Client__contains='ipsos')
```

That said, you have not posted your models, and we’d need to see those first to help you out with writing the query.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  but I need using Q object because I make dynamic query.

Comment: Sorry @NhatAnh, I don’t understand what you mean.  The qs above matches the SQL you posted.

Comment: I need like same:
qs = PuzzMeetingCandidats.objects.filter(
    Q(canceled=False), 
    Q(meeting__Client__contains='ipsos'))
because my question just only a part of full query.

Comment: @2ps moral of the story is don't answer vague questions like this